# Adding custom paper sizes to named printers

Tags: c#

I am using the code uploaded to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers.  On the website it is working fine, but when I use a shared printer I'm getting this problem.

```
Failed to open \\shivarajm\EPSON LX -300 +II ESC/P Printer ,System Error
```

Comment: A `shred printer`? Assuming you mean a `Shared Printer`: did you check the security settings?

Comment: Yes i have given Full Permission